What is Savitakkasavicārasutta about?
What are your thoughts about this following passage:

“And what is the path that leads to the unconditioned? Immersion with
placing the mind and keeping it connected. Immersion without placing
the mind, but just keeping it connected. Immersion without placing the
mind or keeping it connected. …” -Savitakkasavicārasutta


The Savitakkasavicārasutta is about the four jhanas as the path to the unconditioned (Nibbana).
The translation of 'avitakkavicāramatto' as 'without placing the mind, but just keeping it connected' sounds questionable to me. I cannot imagine vicara (exploration) without vitakka (directedness). 'Avitakkavicāramatto' could possibly simply mean 'without vitakka & vicara to some extent'.

PTS Pali English Dictionary
Matta
adjective
“by measure,”
as much as, i.e. only, a mere, even as little as
as much as, so much, some, enough (of);
Matta

Regardless, this set of dhamma appears to be Abhidhamma later placed into the Suttas, given this set of dhammas is found only four times, i.e., once in each major Nikaya, in the Suttas, specifically in the later DN 34 (merely lists of dhammas), AN 8.63 & MN 128, but found in eighteen places plus a further five places plus a further three places plus a further two places in the later Abhidhamma and once in the later Paṭisambhidāmagga. Generally, when a dhamma is only found once in the SN but found many times in later texts, it has been inserted into the SN at a later time.
To reiterate, avitakkavicāramatto is found in around 29 places in later texts but absent from probably hundreds (less four) suttas about jhana. We can be confident the Buddha never taught this irrelevant illogical idea. The Buddha taught four jhanas rather than five jhanas.

And what, bhikkhus, is right concentration? Here, bhikkhus, secluded
from sensual pleasures, secluded from unwholesome states, a bhikkhu
enters and dwells in the first jhana, which is accompanied by thought
and examination, with rapture and happiness born of seclusion. With
the subsiding of thought and examination, he enters and dwells in the
second jhana, which has internal confidence and unification of mind,
is without thought and examination, and has rapture and happiness born
of concentration. With the fading away as well of rapture, he dwells
equanimous and, mindful and clearly comprehending, he experiences
happiness with the body; he enters and dwells in the third jhana of
which the noble ones declare: ‘He is equanimous, mindful, one who
dwells happily.’ With the abandoning of pleasure and pain, and with
the previous passing away of joy and displeasure, he enters and dwells
in the fourth jhana, which is neither painful nor pleasant and
includes the purification of mindfulness by equanimity. This is called
right concentration.
SN 45.8


[The sutta and it's previous and next suttas][1] are talking about Magga-Appana-Jhana [Eight Noble Truth Attaining Moment].

“Katamo ca, bhikkhave, asaṅkhatagāmimaggo? Savitakkasavicāro samādhi, avitakkavicāramatto samādhi, avitakkaavicāro samādhi—ayaṁ vuccati, bhikkhave, asaṅkhatagāmimaggo …pe….

What is the way to attain Asankhata [Nibbana]?

Concentration meditation supporting by repeatedly thinking on only one [insight] meditation object and keeping thinking on only one [insight] meditation object. (insight meditation object is from "vipassana" in previous sutta and from "asankhata" word, only one is "ekaggata" word which means united mind and mental qualities on the only one object)

Concentration meditation supporting by just keeping thinking on only one meditation object, no need to repeat thinking [more power].

Concentration meditation on only one object without support, no need of repeating and no need to keep thinking.



AvitakkaVicaramattaSamadhi has proved by uncountable noble-one who meditated the meditation hard and many of them  also memorized Tipitaka Pali in their mind because Theravada have the Vinaya rule to memorize Sutta Pali, so Theravada Monk can't avoid reciting and memorizing.
Only in Sutta, this set of Dhamma found in 5 Nikaya and more than 7 suttas, 10 times. You all can prove in this link.
5 Nikaya are from [4 monk groups][3]. Sariputta's students are  just a group of them to keeping memorize Suttas in MajjhimaNikaya and other canon by Sariputta.

i scored this answer down because the following is obviously unsubstantiated (false; ignoble) speech: "AvitakkaVicaramattaSamadhi has proved by uncountable noble-one who meditated the meditation "

Editing cutting off reference paper link is like a baby who say I don't like this one so I will hide it.  @DhammaDhatu

Hello. This is not a discussion forum. We cannot quote from other answers. You should not have pasted parts of my answer into your answer. But I am not a moderator. You can re-type the missing link into your answer (because i mistakenly deleted the link due to your method of formatting).

No, keep it right there for people see that you've done.

While meditating immersion arises. There various types of immersion. Immersion can be immersion in process of breathing , in the process of walking , in the process of listening , in the process of lying , in the process of defecating , in the process of understanding, in the process of cooking etc …
Other than immersion there is a connection at the level of consciousness. Connection to higher or lower realms. There is also a possibility of no connection at all.
Buddha is just elucidating the importance of immersion and possible configurations of immersion and connection.
With every state equanimity(uppekha) must be maintained because all states of existence is Dukkha or suffering.
Blue_eggo asked in commentsdoes this prove we are puppets? The answer is simple.
Puppet is not me , not mine neither myself. Conversely, Master is not me , mine or myself.
